# App store: Why is there sometimes a developer name and a seller name

Tags: ios, app-store

I know you provide the company name and the seller name on itunes connect, but I don´t get why some apps on the app store show (at the app information block) a seller name, some show a developer name, and some show both.

1. Anyone knows when the developer name and when the seller name is shown?
2. Is it possible to alter the developer´s name to not match the seller name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The Seller name is the 'legal entity' name that you used to enroll to the Apple Developer Program. If you're a company that would be your official company name.
- The Developer name is the 'company name' you choose when you first create the app in iTunes Connect. That can be different from your 'legal entity name'. This is also what is shown below the app name at the top of the app description page.

I haven't seen cases where the 'Developer' is missing, but I have seen cases where there is no 'Seller', which I think happens for individual developers who enroll to the Apple Developer Program as individuals (not as a company).

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html

Comment: What if you have wrong legal enitity info? Will it cause problems later?